# C++ Delete pointer to a class based on its variable

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, pointers, vector

I have a "map" with a pointer to a class like this "`map <int, PointerToAClass1*> myMap`".

Inside each pointer "PointerToAClass1*" I have a "vector", the vector itself contains pointers to a different class like this "`vector <PointerToAClass2*> myVector`".

The class pointed to by "PointerToAClass2*" has a "int variable", the name of the int variable is called the "uniqueCustomerNumber".

How would you write code to find and delete a "PointerToAClass2*" BASED ON finding it via its "uniqueCustomerNumber"?

Comment: First, most C++ programmers wouldn't write code that uses pointers in so many places.

Comment: You have to iterate through all `PointerToAClass1` in `myMap` and for every one of them for each of `PointerToAClass2` in their `myVector` until you find the correct one - that's rather straightforward, where are you having trouble with it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is an assignment that I got in school. I'm not very experienced yet with C++, there's so many pointers and layers to this question that my head is spinning by even thinking how I'd start to solve this. I'll try to eventually come up with something.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).